# C# - Освобождение файла

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Есть BinaryReader и BinaryWriter, которые одновременно пишут и читают. Есть progressBar. При закрытии приложения во время работы получаю Exception в progressBar и с помощью делегата делаю Close() & Dispose() BinaryReader, BinaryWriter и FileStream, который используется в BinaryReader. Тем не менее файл почему то не освобождается.

streamRead - FileStream; reader - BinaryReader;

```
using (streamRead = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            reader = new BinaryReader(streamRead);
```

writer - BinaryWriter

```
 using (writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(this.txbxArchivePath.Text + @"\" + this.txbxArchiveName.Text + ".Haffman", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))){ }
```

метод, который вызываю с помощью делегата:

```
private void DisposeAll()
    {
        this.reader.Close();
        this.writer.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        this.reader.Dispose();
        this.writer.Dispose();
        streamRead.Dispose();

        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: текст исключения приведи

Comment: System.IO.IOException: 'Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл используется другим процессом.'

Comment: `File.Open` возвращает `FileStream`. Его нужно сохранить в отдельную переменную (поле) и тоже закрывать/диспозить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На MSDN [пишут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> "Не прерывайте поток, выполняющий операцию чтения. Несмотря на то, что приложение может отображаться для успешного выполнения после поток не заблокирован, прерывания может привести к снижению производительности и надежности приложения." скорее всего это и имелось в виду

Наверняка, это и имелось в виду, что выполнение методов `Close() & Dispose()` может выполниться некорректно.

Попробуйте такой пример:

```
 class MyReader
{
    bool _breakReader = false;

    public void Close()
    {
        _breakReader = true;
    }

    public byte[] Read(string file)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        try
        {

            using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(file,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];
                //Здесь можно указать нужный буфер 
                int numBytesToRead = 1024*1024; //1 МБ
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, 
                        numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                    // Здесь будет прерывание считывания
                    if (n == 0 || _breakReader )
                        break;

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }
                numBytesToRead = bytes.Length;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ioEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

В итоге получается, что мы считываем файл по одному мегабайту, если во время считывания флаг изменился на `true`, то мы прерываем цикл считывания и корректно закрываем `FileStream`

Comment: Почему не BufferedStream?

Comment: @Sergey, мне не понятен ваш вопрос. Если вам нужна оптимизация - используйте буферы, не нужна - можете не использовать.

Comment: Я понял. Хотел узнать есть ли какие нибудь причины не использовать BufferedStream. Спасибо за ответ!